# Insert a page break after specific string from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have made a code that needs to make page-breaks after certain number of new lines or words. I have set up an array that tell me where it should cut in my element. As you can see in my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czxeLz3g/5/) you can see a `console.log();` that shows I need to cut the text.

I would like to get help on how to create a closing `</div>` inserted after the specific string from my `array()`. I would like to have a closing `</div>` and a creation of a new `<div>`

More details about the code

```
// $(this)
$(this) = $('.c_84');
```

The HTML example

```
<div class=" onerow counting_1"><div class="newDiv"></div>
   <div class="onefield c_6937">
      <!-- This is where I want to generate the new divs -->
      <table class="textarea" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="value"><!-- Content String --></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code logic so far.

```
// The class c_6937 is the class test in my jsFiddle
// I did this just to remove extra html and focus on the problem

// Start
$(this).find('.c_6937').parent().prepend('<div class="newDiv">');
var countReqNumberOfPages = newChunk.length;
for (var key in newChunk) {
    // If we find the first chunk, insert </div><div class="newDiv"> after it.
}

// End
$(this).find('.c_6937').parent().append('</div>');
```

Could it be possible to run a str_replace() function inside my array() and replace the current string with the exact same string plus the closing divs?

---

EDIT 1 : I added extra comments in the code for a better understanding of the problem and added a possible solution.

Comment: can you be some more specific, like where do you get newChunk from, where is the element with the class c_6937, how and where you are using your code logic? it would be better if you share the HTML and the way you initialize the script.

Comment: @Snm : If you check the jsFiddle script, you can see that I have the <div class="c_6937"></div> that contains strings. I need to break this string into pages with the parameters I seted.

I edited the post to be more specific.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you can prepend just the opening portion of a div and then just the closing portion of the div. I think the HTML string parameter needs to be complete ***and*** valid html.

Comment: If you check my code, I do a prepend then I run the for on the array and finally I close the final div. There is maybe a simplier way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you are after something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var wordsPerLine = 15;
var minWordsPerLine = 5;
var linesPerPage = 30;
var linesToStopAfter = [];


function checkForDot(pos,masterArray){
  if(pos < 0){

    return false;
  }
  var line = masterArray[pos];
  if(line.indexOf('.') !== -1){
    return line;
  }
  else{

    return checkForDot(pos-1,masterArray);
  }
}

function chunk(lines) {

  var masterLines = [];
  for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) { 

      var sentence = [];
      var wordsList = lines[i].split(" ");
      var wordCount = 0;
      for (j = 0; j < wordsList.length; j++) { 

        if(wordCount >= wordsPerLine){

          wordCount = 0;
          masterLines.push(sentence.join(" "));
          sentence = [];
          sentence.push(wordsList[j]);
        }
        else{

          sentence.push(wordsList[j]);
        }

        wordCount++;        
      }

      masterLines.push(sentence.join(" "));           
  }

    return masterLines
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var html = $("#test").html();
    $("#test").html('<div class="newDiv">'+html+'</div>');
    var lines = chunk($("#test").text().split("\n"));
    var count = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < lines.length; k++) { 
      count++;
      if(count >= linesPerPage){
        count = 0;
        linesToStopAfter.push(checkForDot(k,lines));
      }
    }

    for(j=0; j<linesToStopAfter.length;j++)
    {
        toreplace = $("#test").html().replace(linesToStopAfter[j], linesToStopAfter[j]+"</div><div class='newDiv'>");
        $("#test").html(toreplace)
    }
    cleanedhtml = $("#test").html().replace(/<\s*div[^>]*><\s*\/\s*div>/g,"");
    $("#test").html(cleanedhtml)
});

</script>
```

Comment: hope you can take it further with your html

Comment: At first sight, I looks pretty good ! I placed this code in the jsFiddle and It looks like it could work. Thank you Snm, I might be good to continue from there. Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks and if that was the logic you were looking for please accept the answer

Comment: There is just one small thing before accepting the answer. If you go on the updated version : https://jsfiddle.net/czxeLz3g/6/. You will see that the code create empty div between. Is there any way we could remove them?

Comment: hi @PatricePoliquin, i couldn't reproduce that problem in my local system. But it can be removed by a small regular expression.. I'm updating the answer with the regular expression

Comment: Seems to be working with your regular expression. I'll give it a look tonight and give feedback or mark as answered.